# Error al actualizar un registro de una BD en SQLServer desde JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema en JAVA para Reservas de Habitación de un Hotel, la verdad soy nuevo en esto, pero ahí voy que quiero.

Bueno en JAVA todo lo tengo ordenado en paquetes, un paquete llamado Datos con todas la clases que contienen los datos de mis tablas en SqlServer para luego hacer formularios desde JAVA para ingresar, actualizar y eliminar cualquier datos desde el sistema.

Otro paquete llamado Logica donde se encuentran todas las funciones desde la función que me permite conectarme a la Base de Datos y otra llamada Presentación a cual tendrá los formularios para manipular desde ahí la Base de Datos y por último uno llamado Files que contiene las imágenes de los botones algunos label y la barra de menú de mi sistema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy comenzando a realizar el sistema, he comenzado a realizar el formulario para ingresar las habitaciones, haciendo un llamado a la clase fhabitación la cual contiene todas las funciones para insertar, editar y eliminar datos de mi tabla habitacion que se en cuentra en la base de datos en SQLServer.

El punto es que yo yá probé la conexión y todo "OK", también pobré a insertar y a eliminar una habitación desde el formulario hecho en JAVA y también me deja hacerlo perfectamente,  el problema esta cuando yo intento actualizar un dato de la tabla habitación desde el formulario, me manda un mensaje que dice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se a que se refiere, yo estoy actualizado la tabla según el idhabitación el cual se ingresa a la tabla de manera automática ya que tiene la propiedad identity la cual hace un AUTO_INCREMENT, a continuación compartó el codigo de mi funcion fhabitacion:

```
public class fhabitacion {
    // Declaración de variables
    private conexion sqlserver = new conexion();
    private Connection cn = sqlserver.conectar();
    private String sSQL = "";
    public Integer totalregistros;

    public DefaultTableModel mostrar (String buscar){
        DefaultTableModel modelo;

        String [] titulo = {"ID","Número","Piso","Descripción","Caracteristicas","Precio","Estado","Tipo habitación"};

        String [] registro = new String[8];

        totalregistros=0;

        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulo);

        sSQL="select * from habitacion where piso like '%"+ buscar + "%' order by idhabitacion";

        try {
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

            while(rs.next()){
                registro [0]=rs.getString("idhabitacion");
                registro [1]=rs.getString("numero");
                registro [2]=rs.getString("piso");
                registro [3]=rs.getString("descripcion");
                registro [4]=rs.getString("caracteristicas");
                registro [5]=rs.getString("precio_diario");
                registro [6]=rs.getString("estado");
                registro [7]=rs.getString("tipo_habitacion");

                totalregistros=totalregistros+1;
                modelo.addRow(registro);
            }
            return modelo;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean insertar(vhabitacion dts){
        sSQL="insert into habitacion (numero,piso,descripcion,caracteristicas,precio_diario,estado,tipo_habitacion)" + 
                "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {

            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
            pst.setString(1, dts.getNumero());
            pst.setString(2, dts.getPiso());
            pst.setString(3, dts.getDescripcion());
            pst.setString(4, dts.getCaracteristica());
            pst.setDouble(5, dts.getPrecio_diario());
            pst.setString(6, dts.getEstado());
            pst.setString(7, dts.getTipo_habitacion());

            int n = pst.executeUpdate();

            if(n!=0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean editar(vhabitacion dts){
        sSQL="update habitacion set numero=?,piso=?,descripcion=?,caracteristicas=?,precio_diario=?,estado=?,tipo_habitacion=?"+
                "where idhabitacion=?";

        try {

            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
            pst.setString(1, dts.getNumero());
            pst.setString(2, dts.getPiso());
            pst.setString(3, dts.getDescripcion());
            pst.setString(4, dts.getCaracteristica());
            pst.setDouble(5, dts.getPrecio_diario());
            pst.setString(6, dts.getEstado());
            pst.setString(7, dts.getTipo_habitacion());
            pst.setInt(8, dts.getIdhabitacion());

            int n = pst.executeUpdate();

            if(n!=0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean eliminar(vhabitacion dts){
        sSQL="delete from habitacion where idhabitacion=?";
        try {

            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
            pst.setInt(1, dts.getIdhabitacion());

            int n = pst.executeUpdate();

            if(n!=0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregando un espacio antes del where en esta linea de codigo:

```
 sSQL="update habitacion set numero=?,piso=?,descripcion=?,caracteristicas=?,precio_diario=?,estado=?,tipo_habitacion=?"+
            " where idhabitacion=?";
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, esa era la solución a mi problema solo agregué el espacio y listo.